# Converting / mapping Java code to Dart

Tags: java, dart

My server is written in Java (on GAE).  It includes some data classes that I share with an Android client, and would now like to also share with a Dart web client.

By 'share' I mean that I serialize them to JSON and use HTTP or GCM to sync them between client and server.

So, I'm looking for a tool that will generate Dart equivalents for the relevant Java classes, so I don't have to create them manually.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-endpoints/) does this (converts data classes from GAE languages to client languages) but Dart is not currently amongst the support languages.

I guess GCE could be used to  generate js, which could then be used in Dart app, but that is not ideal.  So I think this is a possible solution but not an adequate one.

The other problem with this is that the code conversion of is tightly bound to the GCE service - it can't be used independently of GCE and the only way to get GCE to convert your classes is to include them in a GCE interface.

(If they added Dart support to GCE, made the code translator more independent of GCE, and added some features such as an @Ignore attribute, I think it would be very useful!)

Answer (score 2):

The "[ad-hoc Java-to-Dart translator](https://gist.github.com/sma/8180927)" was "written in three days" by Stefan Matthias Aust (last revised on 2014-01-03).  The author notes that "there might be errors", and that "I didn't cover annotations and some esotheric[sic] generics syntax."

He provides some useful guidelines for keeping your Java code dart friendly:

"Because Dart doesn't support overloading methods, I strongly recommend to first rename (using your favorite IDE) those methods in Java. I also noticed that Dart doesn't like if types, fields, or methods have the same name. Again, I recommend to rename all such occurrences before translating.  He also notes that Dart doesn't support a character type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package to generate Dart client code for Google Cloud Endpoints http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/discovery_api_client_generator.

I also successfully used Protocol Buffers for a similar scenario
- http://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=protobuf
- http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/protobuf_builder
See also https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: Ah, good to know that Dart has a GCE generator too.  I believe, however, that I would have to create fake endpoints that included my data classes in order to take advantage of this.  That is do-able, but not ideal.

Comment: Don't you use GCE for you Android app? I guess some Java functionality instead when both server and client are Java.

Comment: Actually no, instead I share the code between the Android & GAE projects, and then use a single generic endpoints to send/receive generic JSON objects.  I have many different data types, and this approach is much easier (for me) then having a separate endpoint and CRUD functions for each type.

Comment: I guess Protocol Buffers is more similar to your current approach then, but supports different languages. I haven't created GCEs yet myself (only used) so I have no idea what needs more expenditure.

Comment: It sounds like PB generates classes for both ends (Java & Dart in my case) based on the .proto file, rather then being able to work from my existing Java classes.  I actually considered using PB when I started - I opted for JSON instead was because it looked like Google was standardizing on JSON - not because JSON is better but because it is more widely used.

Comment: Yet, I think so too. PB is used internally a lot (AFAIK) because of its efficiency but for public interfaces mostly JSON is used.